# How to set cookie in Vaadin and get it in front end?

Tags: java, extjs, vaadin7

I have set the user defined cookie in Vaadin response object and tried to get that cookie in Ext-JS file but I was not able to get it, just getting as null value. Can anyone give me an ***IDEA*** of

****How to get that cookie Or Is there any alternative way to set user defined cookie in Vaadin response and get it in client side?****

***Here is my scenario :***

Both frameworks are running in different applications such as Vaadin in 3030 port and Ext-JS in 7070 as well. I have set the cookie in Vaadin framework and tried to get it in Ext-JS after redirect the page from Vaadin to Ext-JS.

***Please find the code below what I have tried,***

To redirect page from Vaadin to Ext-JS :

```
UI mainWindow = operationContext.getMainWindow();
mainWindow.getPage().setLocation("http://localhost:7070/index.jsp");
```

Set the cookie in Vaadin :

```
Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("tempKey", "Hi");
VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().addCookie(myCookie);
```

Get the cookie in Ext-JS :

```
Ext.util.Cookies.get('tempKey');
```

Comment: In chrome developer tools or firebug is the cookie being added under the sources?

Comment: Yes, I can see that cookie in firefox developer tool console.

Comment: Is that cookie appearing on the vaadin page or the redirected extjs page or both?  I'm curious if it doesn't appear on the ExtJS page because of the redirect.

Comment: Yes, It's appearing on Vaadin page but not in Ext-JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the IDEA to set the cookie in vaadin. Please find the code snippet below what i have tried.

I have set the cookie in Vaadin using the javascript api and now I am able to read this cookie in Ext-JS page.

```
Page().getJavaScript().execute("document.cookie='"+key+"="+value+"; path=/'");
```